# Catching exceptions created by worker threads in Main thread

Tags: java, spring, exception, threadpoolexecutor

How do we handle the Exceptions generated from threads started by ThreadPoolTaskExecutor in main thread?

```
public static void main(String[] args){
     ApplicationContext context =  new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
     ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executer = (ThreadPoolTaskExecutor)context.getBean("taskExecutor_test");

     for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        executer.execute(new RunnableImpl()); //If any of the thread create exception
     }

    //need to catch the exceptions here.
}
```

*[like what we do with 'setUncaughtExceptionHandler' in normal Thread]*

Comment: Use `submit` instead of `execute` and query the returned `Future` for exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When submitting tasks to the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`, you're expecting those tasks to be run asynchronously, so your code can't `catch` and handle exceptions unless you block and wait for them to happen.

To do this, use [`ThreadPoolTaskExecutor#submit(Runnable)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html#submit-java.lang.Runnable-) which returns a `Future`. You can then call [`Future#get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28%29) to block the current thread and wait for either the task to complete or for an exception to be thrown (which completes (fails) the task). If it's a long running task, you can also poll for its completion with its `Future#isDone()` or the overloaded `get(..)` method.